# arctan maps the unit disk onto a band around the imaginary axis

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be the unit disk; that is, $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ |z|<1\}$. Let $B\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be some band around the imaginary axis: $B=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ |\text{Re}(z)|<\pi/4\}$.

Why does it hold that the principal branch of $\arctan$ maps $D$ *conformally* onto $V$?

Comment: I assume that the question is why the map is conformal, not why $D$ is mapped onto $B$. Observe that any branch $f(z)$ of $\arctan(z)$ defined on $D$ has a nowhere vanishing derivative, as $f'(z) =\frac{1}{1+z^2}$. Any holomorphic function $F(z)$ defined on a domain $U$ with $F'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in U$ is a conformal (not necessarily injective) map of $U$ onto $f(U)$. The reason is that multiplication by a non-zero complex number ($F'(z)$ in this case) is a linear map that preserves the angle between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the tangent vectors to two curves passing through $z$).

Comment: Yes, the question was about conformity (hence I have emphasized the "conformally"). I appreciate your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt:
let $U=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\ \text{Re}(z)>0\right\}$. Define
$g:V\to U$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
  g(z) = g(x+yi) = \exp(-2y + 2xi).
\end{equation*}

We have that $g$ maps $V$ conformally to $U$. Now define $h:U\to D$ as
follows:
\begin{equation*}
  h(z) = \frac{i(1-z)}{1+z}
\end{equation*}

We have that $h$ maps $U$ conformally to $D$ (it is a Möbius transformation). It follows that
\begin{equation*}
  \tan{z} = \frac{\sin z}{\cos z}
  = \frac{i\left(1-e^{2iz}\right)}{1+e^{2iz}}
  = h\circ g (z)
\end{equation*}
maps $V$ conformally to $D$, thus the principal branch of $\arctan{z}$ maps
$D$ conformally to $V$.